# Perforce branching and re-running setups

Tags: git, branch, perforce

I was watching a presentation from Atlassian on Git Branching for Agile Teams (webinar). I really like the branching per task since we use Jira to track bugs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SZ7kSQ2424

However we do use Perforce instead of Git and my concern would be to have a task to fix a typo where we would have to create a full branch and run all the installation scripts needed in order to just fix a spelling issue. Does Perforce has a way to switch between branches where we could quickly pick up an continue work without having to have 100s of branches and installations?

Comment: You could investigate the Perforce feature known as `Task Streams`; it was designed to be applicable to this type of work flow.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately we don't have streams available but thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is that because you're using an old version of Perforce or because of an organizational restriction?

Comment: I am not sure, I can see options for Streams in the Preferences panel, but when I go to "File>New>Stream" Stream is grayed out.